# PHP, imploding an array sent via axios

Tags: php

I'm trying to implode an array into a comma separated string for sql usage, but my current implode function gives my sql a syntax error because it says 'AND number in ({"num":"145"})`

My php has:

```
public function getInfo($query, array $num = []){
    
    $numClause    = empty($num)      ? '' : 'AND NUM IN ('.implode(',',$num).')';

    dd($num);
}
```

That dump/die shows this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "{"num":"145"}"
  1 => "{"num":"325"}"
]
```

So I'm sending the array to this function from an axios call, I'm getting the array in the function as shown in the dump, but the implode is not creating a comma separation of 145,325,etc.

What am I doing wrong with this implode?

Comment: The `implode` function will split the array separate by comma. So your result is:
`{"num":"145"},{"num":"325"}`. So what you are receiving from Axios is a JSON structure.

Comment: If you change `dd($num);` to `dd(json_decode($num));` what is the output?

Comment: @knot22 it says it expects param 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Try it again with this `exit('<pre>' . print_r(json_decode($num, true),1) . '</pre>');` instead of the `dd();`

Comment: @knot22 same error unfortunately